# What does PURE CONFIGURATION mean in ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I was going through Form Creation in ZF2 and I read the following statement.
"
You can create the entire form, and input filter, using the Factory. This is particularly nice if you want to store your forms as ***pure configuration***; you can simply pass the configuration to the factory and be done."
Can anybody tell in detail what does PURE CONFIGURATION mean?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you're able to store your forms within any config file, e.g. `module.config.php` and then pass this configuration key into the form factory. This is similar what has been done in ZF1 often times, too.

This whole process is done through the [`Zend\Form\Factory`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/Factory.php) and if you check out the source code you'll see that you could pass it the following array to create a Form

```
$someConfig = array(
  'form-key-name' => array(
    'fieldsets' => array(
        'fieldset_1' => array(
            'elements' => array(
                'elem_x' => array(/** Single Form-Element Array*/)
            ),
            'fieldsets' => array(
                'fs_y' => array(/** More Sub-Fieldset Array*/)
            ),
        )
    )
  )
);
```

Note that this example is quite incomplete (missing `name => foo`), `hydrator` configuration, `inputFilter` configuration, etc... but as it is this should give you a idea of what's meant by that statement.

Using the above-mentioned configuration then you can pass it to the factory

```
$factory = new \Zend\Form\Factory();
$form    = $factory->createForm($someConfig['form-key-name']);
```